# How to delete multiple rows in gridview then update data in database?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I want to delete some selected rows of data contained in grid view by pressing delete button, how to do it ?

This code works if data is not bound to the database:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row  in DGV1.SelectedRows)
{
     DGV1.Rows.RemoveAt(row.Index);
}
```

And this is my code to clear data in gridview based on value in Z_1_lblSupplier_Name.Text.

```
string sqlquery = "DELETE FROM tb_supplier_list WHERE Supplier_name='" + Z_1_lblSupplier_Name.Text + "'";

MySqlConnection mysqlconn = new MySqlConnection(mainconn);

MySqlCommand sqlcmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlquery, mysqlconn);
MySqlDataReader sdr;

mysqlconn.Open();

sdr = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();
mysqlconn.Close();
```

I don't know how to combine them, I want users to be able to select multiple rows of data in grid view which they want to delete, then simultaneously data in database is also deleted.

Comment: *Removing* a row is very different from **deleting** a row.  You should never, ever have to iterate the rows in a `DataGridView`; instead, use a DataSource.  Delete from there and your DBProvider object will know how to update the DB when you `Update()` the `DataAdapter`.  All the providers work very much the same so you can start with the documentation and tutorials for SQL Server or OleDB and just adjust for MySQL.

Comment: Why do you execute `ExecuteReader`, when that SQL statement quite obviously doesn't return any data?? You should use `ExecuteNonQuery()` instead - best suited for all statements that don't return data sets (like `DELETE`, `INSERT`, and `UPDATE`)

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: @marc_s Ah, looks like I have to change it..

Comment: @marc_s thanks i got a great solution.. i even just realized about SQLinjection.. extra knowledge for me.. thanks a lot.